# neo4j update properties on 10 million nodes

Tags: java, multithreading, neo4j, core-api

I use the neo4j java core api and want to update 10 million nodes. 
I thought it will be better to do it with multithreading but the performance is not that good (35 minutes for setting properties).

To explain: Each node "Person" has at least one relation "POINTSREL" to a "Point" node, which has the property "Points". I want to sum up the points from the "Point" node and set it as property to the "Person" node.

Here is my code:

```
Transaction transaction = service.beginTx();
ResourceIterator<Node> iterator = service.findNodes(Labels.person);
transaction.success();
transaction.close();

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

while(iterator.hasNext()){
    executor.execute(new MyJob(iterator.next()));
}

//wait until all threads are done
executor.shutdown();

try {
    executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And here the runnable class

```
private class MyJob implements Runnable {

    private Node node;

    /* collect useful parameters in the constructor */
    public MyJob(Node node) {
        this.node = node;
    }

    public void run() {
        Transaction transaction = service.beginTx();
        Iterable<org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship> rel = this.node.getRelationships(RelationType.POINTSREL, Direction.OUTGOING);

        double sum = 0;
        for(org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship entry : rel){
            try{
                sum += (Double)entry.getEndNode().getProperty("Points");
            } catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        this.node.setProperty("Sum", sum);

        transaction.success();
        transaction.close();
    }
}
```

Is there a better (faster) way to do that?

About my setting:
AWS Instance with 8 CPUs and 32GB ram

neo4j-wrapper.conf

```
# Java Heap Size: by default the Java heap size is dynamically
# calculated based on available system resources.
# Uncomment these lines to set specific initial and maximum
# heap size in MB.
wrapper.java.initmemory=16000
wrapper.java.maxmemory=16000
```

neo4j.properties

```
# The type of cache to use for nodes and relationships.
cache_type=soft
cache.memory_ratio=30.0
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=2G
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=7G
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=2G
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=2G
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=512M
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that there was, amongst others, a problem with the property "cache_type=soft". I set it to "cache_type=none" and the duration of the execution decreased from 30 minutes to 2 minutes. After some updates there were always threads which were blocked for about 30 seconds - changing this property helps to avoid these blockings. I will search for a more detail explantation.

Answer (score 1):

From my perspective there is something that can be improved.

### Offtopic

If you are using Java 7 (or greater) consider using [try with resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to handler transaction. It will prevent you from errors.

### Performance

First of all - batching. Currently you are:

- Creating Job
- Starting thread (actually, there is pool in executor)
- Starting transaction

For **each** node. You should consider to make updates in **batches**. This means that you should:

- Collect `N` nodes (i.e. `N`=1000)
- Create single job for `N` nodes
- Create single transaction in job
- Update `N` nodes in that transaction
- Close transaction

### Setup

You have 8 CPU's. That means that you can create bigger thread pool. I think `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(16)` will be OK.

### Hacks

You have 32GB RAM. I can suggest:

- Decrease java heap size to 8GB. From my experience large heap size can lead to large GC pauses and performance degradation
- Increate mapped memory size. Just to make sure that more data can be kept in cache.

Just for your case. If **all** your data can fit in RAM, then you can change `cache_type` to `hard` for this change purposes. [Details](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/configuration-caches.html#_configuration_2).

### Configuration

As you said - you are using Core API. Is this `Embedded` graph database or server `extension`?

If this is `Embedded` graph database - you should verify that your database settings is applied to created instance.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. This is a unmanaged server extension. I also thought about the problem for creating a transaction for each node - this is the first step I will try, to collect some nodes.

Comment: I tried to collect n nodes into on transaction - still no performance improvement, I also set the heap size to 8 GB. Can the property  "dbms.pagecache.memory" affect the performance in my case?

Comment: I also found out that it doesn't matter if I use 1 or 16 Threads in the Threadpool